# How to turn buttons into a dropdown list without losing functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have a code from isotope (combination filters) with specific loaded categories. It's all based on buttons but I need to have lists (select, options). How can I have it with lists without losing any functions, because it's almost perfect how it is, except the buttons. It's very important to me, to have it working like this, especially the selected categories from beginning and showing them selected. Is it possible to change without loss?

One thing more is a problem for me: If you load the site, you see all items for a millisecond. Is there a way to remove that?

Here is the complete code:

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

// build initial combination filter
var $filters = $('.filters');
$filters.find('.button.is-checked').each( function( i, button ) {
  setGroupFilter( button );
});

function setGroupFilter( button ) {
  var $button = $( button );
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $button.parents('.button-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = $button.attr('data-filter');
}

// get initial comboFilter
var comboFilter = getComboFilter()

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.color-shape',
  filter: comboFilter,
});


$filters.on( 'click', '.button', function( event ) {
  setGroupFilter( event.currentTarget );
  // combine filters
  comboFilter = getComboFilter();
  // set filter for Isotope
  $grid.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
  
// flatten object by concatting values
function getComboFilter() {
  var comboFilter = '';
  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    comboFilter += filters[ prop ];
  }
  return comboFilter;
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2) );
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child { border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em; }
.button-group .button:last-child { border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0; }

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ui group */

.ui-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-group h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-group .button-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* color-shape */

.color-shape {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
 
.color-shape.round {
  border-radius: 35px;
}
 
.color-shape.big.round {
  border-radius: 75px;
}
 
.color-shape.red { background: red; }
.color-shape.blue { background: blue; }
.color-shape.yellow { background: yellow; }
 
.color-shape.wide, .color-shape.big { width: 150px; }
.color-shape.tall, .color-shape.big { height: 150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="filters">

  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter=".red">red</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".blue">blue</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow">yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="size">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter=".small">small</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".wide">wide</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".big">big</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".tall">tall</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="color-shape small round red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape small round blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape small round yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape small square red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape small square blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape small square yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide round yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape wide square yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big round red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big round blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big round yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big square red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big square blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape big square yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall round yellow"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square red"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square blue"></div>
  <div class="color-shape tall square yellow"></div>
</div>
```